# Can i use Azure Migrate tool to migrate IBM MQ from on-premise to azure cloud

Tags: azure, migration, ibm-mq, azure-vm, azure-migrate

We plan to migrate our on-premise MQ servers hosted in VMware servers to azure VM. Can I use the Azure Migrate tool to migrate IBM MQ from on-premise to Azure cloud

Answer (score 1):

Azure Migrate can be used as a Migration tool for any on-premises VMs running on VMWare/Hyper-V as well as for physical servers provided, they are running on azure supported operating system.

Here is a list of supported OS for migrating VMs to azure under azure Migrate.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/migrate/migrate-support-matrix-vmware-migration#vm-requirements-agentless
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/migrate/migrate-support-matrix-vmware-migration#vm-requirements-agent-based

Note: There are 2 different ways you can replicate the VMs, agent-based and agent-less for details refer to:

1. [Azure Migrate agentless migration of VMware virtual machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/migrate/concepts-vmware-agentless-migration)
2. [Agent-based migration architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/migrate/agent-based-migration-architecture)

Please note azure migrate replicates the disks from on-premises to azure and during migration phase the VM is created using the replicated disks. Any additional configuration for your application inside the VMs needs to be taken care separately.

For more details refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/migrate/migrate-services-overview